# SpringBoot templates html can not be loaded

Tags: html, spring-boot, templates

I put two html file under `templates` : `index.html` and `test.html`.
`index.html` can be shown correct, and i wan't to show `test.html` by

```
<a href="test.html">Contact Me</a>
```

and then `404` occured.

I have include `thymeleaf` in my project:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I guess test.html must be proceeded by a controller. Does such controller exists?

Comment: @Flocke yeah, i know what's wrong now. i should put `test.html` under `static` instead of `templates`.  And of cause there's no controller for `test.html`, it's just a static html.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i move `test.html` to `static`, and keep `index.html` under `templates`. And now i can load `test.html` in `index.html`. I should keep all static resources under `static` at first.